# I'm getting "Unable to find the socket transport 'http'" error suddenly. It was working fine until we switched networks

Tags: php, fsockopen, getaddrinfo

After a network switch, parts of my program that send data to other servers are no longer working.

I tried the following code:

```
<?php
fsockopen("www.php.net", 80, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);
    if(!$fp) {
        echo "Error: $errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
    } else {
        fputs($fp,"GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n");
        while(!feof($fp)) {
            echo fgets($fp,128);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

After running that code, I am presented with the following error:

> Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (19)

What do I need to check to ensure this works? It's baffling because it was working fine just before switching networks. I'm also getting the **"php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo"** error when I try get_file_contents.

Comment: What google searches have you tried? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [fsock: Unable to find the socket transport "http"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965430/fsock-unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-http)

Comment: I've been at this for 3 days now, so i've searched everything I could find, but not finding much help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening the socket without the protocol part, e.g. just

```
fsockopen("www.php.net", 80, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);
```

I found the answer by doing a google search for

> Unable to find the socket transport "http"

The same answer is in **all of the top 5 results**, so it would have saved you 3 days to just spend 5 seconds copying and pasting the error in to google.

Comment: I did lookup all the first page results for that search term, and none of them solved my problem or were relevant to my issue.

When I remove the 'http://'  like you suggested, I get the following error:
 "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."

Comment: Everything I read regarding the getaddrinfo failed error suggested there were DNS problems. I've called my ISP and the DNS servers are set correctly. Im just stuck.

Comment: So what does your fsockopen line look like now? Please update your question.

Comment: Seems my outgoing requests work when using an ip address instead of a domain name.

Comment: It must be a dns issue then. Are you on a managed server or do you have ssh access?